# How to redirect external URL, which is followed by mysite URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, hyperlink, external

How can I redirect external(outgoing) URLs from my site using .htaccess, so search engines will consider them as local.
Here's an example:

```
http://mysiteurl.com/links?http://externalurl.com
```

I have a plugin that can convert common urls`(like http://externalurl.com)` to the ones above on html-output.

Now all I want is to When `http:// externalurl.com` is clicked, the external link should be executed and the visitor should be transferred to `http://externalurl.com`

I tried using putting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^links?(.*) http://$1/ [L,R=301]
```

But not working as I want. Address bar shows `http://mysiteurl.com/links?http://externalurl.com` Not redirecting, and Getting 404 error.

Any help? Thank U advance all programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rule to

```
RewriteRule ^links$ %{QUERY_STRING} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thapaliyal ji nahi hua yr. No success. Same result.

Comment: Did an update. Does that work? Are there other rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: OK Done it. Think a rewrite rule was conflicting. Thank U with love, as U may be from My state.

Comment: Just for my info, did the update work or what I had answered before? I'll update the answer to what worked for future reference.

Comment: @Elafanto, Thanks for letting me know. Greetings from Mumbai/Rishikesh :)